# Why we need to create a new function instead of using an existing function when calling on('change', new func(){myfunc()})?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onchange

I have a newbie question.

In jQuery, why, when we call the :

```
$('#input').on('change', myfunction());
```

The myfunction() function is not called each time that the "input" field is changed, but only at the first script loading?

And this code works:

```
$('#input').on('change', function() { myfunction(); });
```

I was expecting the same result...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The difference is that in the first example you call the function and pass the result to `on()`. In the second example you just pass the function as such (not calling it). You would have the same effect with `$('#input').on('change',myfunction);`

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are passing **return value** of `myfunction` which is not a `function`. In second example you are passing a variable which is `function`.

Below is the snippet to see the difference

```js
function myfunction(){
  return 'x'
}
console.log(typeof myfunction()) //function

// It means that 'myfunction()' doesnot refer to function but its a 'string' i.e 'x'.

function wrapper(){
  myfunction();
}

console.log(typeof wrapper) //function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#input').on('change', myfunction());
```

to

```
$('#input').on('change', myfunction);
```

and it'll work, too. `myfunction` is a function, `myfunction()` is the *result* of `myfunction` being called.